# Need Help With mysqli PHP select Statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a couple of questions here, so any help will be greatly appreciated. I have three pages here.

```
//Page 1 - Constants

$dbhost = "database.url.com";  //Just made up
$dbname = "dbname";
$dbuser = "dbuser";
$dbpass = "123456";


//Page 2 - The Function

//This is where i need to write the function select information from the database.

include ("include/page1.php");
$DBH = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
function selectInfo(){
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM information LIMIT ?,?");
}
//This function obviously is not complete because I keep recieving different error messages. I guess i cannot figure out how to write a prepared select statement. Need some help here.


//Page 3 - Where the function is called and where the user would be
 include ("include/page2.php");

//need to be able to call the function here with variables set.

$start = 0;
$end = 5;
selectInfo();
echo the data that i need in the database.
```

This probably looks like a complete mess, but hopefully you can get the idea i am trying to do here. I would like to be able to fetch the data so that i can display it something like

```
echo $stmt->title;
echo $stmt->id;
```

if that is possible. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the `bind_param` and `execute` method on your mysqli object:

```
$DBH->bind_param("ii", $start, $end);
```

And then execute the statement:

```
$DBH->execute();
```

Just have a close look at the [mysqli API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

From [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) first example.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 150,5";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    /* execute statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $code);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $name, $code);
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

@mcbeav

You should change your function:

```
function selectInfo(){
    $stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM information LIMIT ?,?");
}
```

To something like this:

```
function selectInfo($limit, $offset){
    $stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM information LIMIT ?,?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $limit, $offset);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Other stuff to get your values from this query
    ...

    // Return the object with the results
    return $values;
}
```

Comment: thanks! when calling the function from  page 3, how should i bind the parameters? should i do so in page 2, but set the variables in page 3? The variables will change. so for example just add the first line of your code to page number 2, then when calling the function in page 3 set the variables. ex: Page - 3 - $start = 0; $end = 5; selectInfo();

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need is explained in the [mysqli_prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) documentation.